# Is there support for presenting a UIActivityViewController with a preview image that gets loaded after the view controller is displayed?

Tags: ios, swift, uiactivityviewcontroller

I'm trying to display a preview image in a `UIActivityViewController`. This preview image is from a remote url so it'd require time to load. I'd like the placeholder to be empty initially to avoid blocking displaying the `UIActivityViewController` and then for it to display while I render the `UIActivityViewController`. Is it possible for the image to be generated asynchronously? From the docs I've seen on `UIActivityViewController` I haven't found any example of asynchronously loading the preview image. [image]